# Radix sort using bitwise operations

Tags: c++, sorting, radix

First of all this is homework , and I found another topic talking about the same subject but there was no answer. Here is the problem:

> Sorting by bit based on the assumption that the values ​​to be sorted are integers coded B bits (and therefore between 0 and 2B-1).

The main problem is how to make this kind of sort. Should I convert each integer to bits and compare them?
Please do not give me the solution just a hint or an explanation of how to do it.
Thanks for your help !
[EDIT]
I found this script in the internet but i did not understand how it works :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

// Radix sort comparator for 32-bit two's complement integers
class radix_test
{
    const int bit; // bit position [0..31] to examine
public:
    radix_test(int offset) : bit(offset) {} // constructor

    bool operator()(int value) const // function call operator
    {
        if (bit == 31) // sign bit
            return value < 0; // negative int to left partition
        else
            return !(value & (1 << bit)); // 0 bit to left partition
    }
};

// Least significant digit radix sort
void lsd_radix_sort(int *first, int *last)
{
    for (int lsb = 0; lsb < 32; ++lsb) // least-significant-bit
    {
        std::stable_partition(first, last, radix_test(lsb));
    }
}

// Most significant digit radix sort (recursive)
void msd_radix_sort(int *first, int *last, int msb = 31)
{
    if (first != last && msb >= 0)
    {
        int *mid = std::partition(first, last, radix_test(msb));
        msb--; // decrement most-significant-bit
        msd_radix_sort(first, mid, msb); // sort left partition
        msd_radix_sort(mid, last, msb); // sort right partition
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int data[] = { 170, 45, 75, -90, -802, 24, 2, 66 };

    lsd_radix_sort(data, data + 8);
    // msd_radix_sort(data, data + 8);

    std::copy(data, data + 8, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The range of an unsigned integer value of b bits is 0 to 2**b-1.

Comment: What does "convert each integer to bits" even *mean*? You can't just string words together and hope that a program comes out...

Comment: @KerrekSB: I mean convert a numbers to binary and compare with others binary numbers (this a suggestion not a solution)

Comment: What does "convert a number to binary" mean? That also makes no sense.

Comment: means convert 5 to binary it will be string equal to 101 for example

Comment: found this link breaking integer to 4 char http://www.codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you don't need to convert an integer to bits, because it already is stored as bits.  An `int` is usually 4 bytes, so 32 bits.  You can access the bits using bit operators.

Radix sort is shown here in detail. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

This example sorts based on base 10 digits.

To sort based on bit, you would change the algorithm slightly to use 2 instead of 10 in all places:

```
void radixsort(int *a, int n) {
...
  while (m / exp > 0) {
    int bucket[2] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)      bucket[a[i] / exp % 2]++;
    bucket[1] += bucket[0];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) b[--bucket[a[i] / exp % 2]] = a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)      a[i] = b[i];
    exp *= 2;
...
  }
}
```

But if you needed to use bit wise operators instead, you could recognize that anything divided by 2 is simply `>> 1`, multiply by 2 is `<< 1`, and modulo 2 is `&1`.  By replacing `exp` with the bit position, we can rewrite as follows:

```
void radixsort(int *a, int n) {
  int i, b[MAX], m = a[0], bit = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (a[i] > m) m = a[i];

  while ((m>>bit) > 0) {
    int bucket[2] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)      bucket[(a[i]>>bit) & 1]++;
    bucket[1] += bucket[0];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) b[--bucket[(a[i]>>bit) & 1]] = a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)      a[i] = b[i];
    bit++;
...
  }
}
```

This sorts using a single bit.  To use multiple bits, you'd need to make it more generic:

```
#define BITS 2
void radixsort(int *a, int n) {
  int i, b[MAX], m = a[0], pos = 0;
  int buckets=1<<BITS;
  int mask=buckets-1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (a[i] > m) m = a[i];

  while ((m>>(pos*BITS)) > 0) {
    int bucket[1<<BITS] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)       bucket[(a[i]>>(pos*BITS)) & mask]++;
    for (i = 1; i < buckets; i++) bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)  b[--bucket[(a[i]>>(pos*BITS)) & mask]] = a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)       a[i] = b[i];
    pos++;
...
  }
}
```

This sorts using two bits, so 4 buckets are used for 00, 01, 10, and 11.  3 bits would use 8 buckets (000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111).

You can see how increasing the BITS will make fewer passes, but the work done in each pass is larger.

Comment: i have alerady seen the article in wikipedia but i did not found anything talking about bit operations

Comment: will using bit operations make it faster than using base 10 or there will be no significant difference?

Comment: @Zolo_Ryan Yes, bit operations are faster because computers don't inherently understand base 10 like we do.  They would need to do a bit of math to determine which base 10 bucket to go into.  But numbers are already stored as bits by the computer, so it doesn't need to do any extra work.  It can almost immediately see which bucket to use.